# Spring tool suite installation on Mac OS Big Sur Beta - Import project not working

Tags: eclipse, macos-catalina, spring-tool-suite

I upgraded Mac OS to BigSur beta and installed the latest version of Spring too suite and facing issue with importing a maven project.

Getting the below error.

```
  1 /Users/test/Documents/test_prj/pom.xml: Operation not permitted
  2 Can not access files from /test/Documents/test_prj/.
```

It was working with the previous version of Mac OS.

Comment: Hi, how exactly you're trying to import this project and have you tried other projects or folder directories?

Comment: most likely an issue with new strict permissions on macOS Big Sur.